# Unlink sometimes fails - needs improvements

Tags: php, delete-file, unlink

I use this custom, simple script I made, somehow it's failing but it always returns true.

This class `unlink` the files that are placed in an array which goes through them then increments the counter on success of a file that was deleted, this is my script:

```
<?php

class Delete 
{
    function deleteFiles($array)
    {
        if(is_array($array))
        {
            $filecount = count($array);
            $count = 0;

            foreach($array as $file)
            {
                if(file_exists($file))
                {
                    $remove = unlink($file);

                    if($remove)
                    {
                        $count++;   
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            if($count == $filecount)
            {
                return true;    
            }
            else
            {
                return false;   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return false;   
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Basically I need improvements on how to make it foolproof so that the images in the array are **completely** deleted not returning true once an unlink has deleted the file when it hasn't, so I have no idea why it's not actually deleting the files properly.

Sometimes it works perfectly.

Comment: Which OS are you using? I've heard of issues when using `unlink` on Windows previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `if($remove)` to `if($remove && !file_exists($file))`

Also, be aware that sometimes an unlink will fail on Windows: http://ie.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php#100580

Comment: I was actually thinking if it would be good if there was a `while` loop, e.g. `while(!file_exists($file) == true){ unlink($file); }` - would that be plausible?

Comment: if the problem is something like file permissions, then that will cause an infinite loop. you need to figure out /why/ are the unlink() calls failing

Answer (score 0):

you could add a call to `is_file()` after the `unlink` to check if the file is still there